# Why does this keyboard shortcut not work in htmx?

Tags: javascript, hotkeys, htmx

- Visit https://htmx.org/examples/keyboard-shortcuts/
- Type alt-shift-D. Nothing.  (This is the bug.)
- Click on the button, changes to "Did it".  (Shows the button works, but not with keyboard shortcuts for me.)

I have no idea how to debug.

I'm using Chrome Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (x86_64) on OS X 10.14.6.

I tried in incognito mode (since that shuts off most? extensions).

I looked in the Chrome debugger console, and see no errors, no warnings.

I tried command-shift-D, in case that worked, but that bookmarks in chrome, so that key combo is taken.

I tried in Safari Version 14.1 (14611.1.21.161.5). Key combo did not work.

I also documented this at https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/467.

Also: I tried `monitor(window, "keydown")` in the chrome debugger and typed in the window. Nothing. I tried `monitor(document, "keydown")`, same thing. I tried `monitor(window, "click")` and clicked on the button. Nothing. The button changed to "Did it!", so I know the click worked. I don't understand how to use the monitor interface.

Comment: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/467

Comment: @Justinas Yes, that's the issue that I filed, and also referenced in this question. I'm asking this question because there's been no progress on the issue.

Comment: So `monitorEvents(window, 'keyup')` returns `{key: "Meta", code: "MetaLeft"}` on Mac when clicking _options_ button